# PySpark: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pre-built 'spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7’ and when I try to start pyspark, I get following message.
Any ideas what could be wrong? I tried using python3, setting SPARK_LOCAL_IP to 127.0.0.1 but same error.

```
~ -> cd /Applications/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/
/Applications/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin -> pyspark
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:24:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
16/12/19 14:50:47 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/12/19 14:50:47 WARN Utils: Your hostname, XXXXXX.com resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using XX.XX.XX.XXX instead (on interface en0)
16/12/19 14:50:47 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 43, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
  File "/Applications/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Applications/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 294, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Applications/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/Applications/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 174, in _do_init
    self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server()
  File "/Applications/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 259, in _start_update_server
    server = AccumulatorServer(("localhost", 0), _UpdateRequestHandler)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Found it. Some how my host mapping was messing it up. Changing it to point to localhost worked.:

/etc/host

#127.0.0.1 XXXXXX.com

127.0.0.1 localhost

Answer (score 1):

In cases when you cannot cleanup /etc/hosts (such as it's being tempered with by some VPN solution), here is a workaround:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def patch_pyspark_accumulators():
    from inspect import getsource
    import pyspark.accumulators as pa
    exec(getsource(pa._start_update_server).replace("localhost", "127.0.0.1"), pa.__dict__)

patch_pyspark_accumulators()
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```